# Closure in Javascript with multiple brackets

Tags: javascript, closures

Could any one explain how this function alert, when more no of brackets of parameters are passed. I could not able to understand it clearly.

```
function sum(a) {

  var sum = a

  function f(b) {
    sum += b
    return f
  }

  f.toString = function() { return sum }

  return f
}

alert( sum(1)(2) )  // 3
alert( sum(5)(-1)(2) )  // 6
alert( sum(6)(-1)(-2)(-3) )  // 0
alert( sum(0)(1)(2)(3)(4)(5) )  // 15
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The first time your function is called, the first value is stored in `sum`. After that `function f(b)` will be returned, maintaining the provisional result in `sum`. With each consecutive call you execute function `f` - you perform `sum += b` and return f again. If a string context is required (such as in the `alert`, or a `console.log`) `f.toString` is called instead, returning the result (`sum`).

```
function sum(a) {

  var sum = a

  function f(b) {
    sum += b
    return f  //<- from second call, f is returned each time
              //   so you can chain those calls indefinitely
              //   function sum basically got "overridden" by f
  }

  f.toString = function() { return sum }

  return f //<- after first call, f is returned
}
```

Explanation:

```
alert( sum(6)(-1)(-2)(-3) )  // 0
           /\ function sum called, f returned
              /\ the returned function f is called, f returns itself
                  /\ again
                     /\ and again
                         /\ at last, alert() requires string context,
                            so f.toString is getting invoked now instead of f
```

Comment: Basically in the first alert sum(1)(2) which is a & b and in the second alert it is sum(6)(-1)(2) now how the function understands that (2) is also f(b) argument.

Comment: @Babu get rid of the thinking of a and b. You could think of `sum()` being called once, initialising `var sum` and then getting overriden after the first call, handling each consecutive call by invoking the `f(b)` (because f itself each time returns itself, thus making it possible to do further chaining) function unless a string context occurs. Clearer now?

Comment: great explanation. Can you please tell me instead of f.toString can you show me code for returning the sum directly.

function sum(a) {

  var sum = a

  function f(b) {
    sum += b
    return sum
  }

 // f.toString = function() { return sum }

  return f
}
sum(1)(2);

Comment: @BabuArumugam: The point is that you cannot… Why would you need this?

Answer (score 3):

The thing to look at is this piece of code

```
function f(b) {
    sum += b
    return f
  }
```

This function returns reference to itself so it can be called as many times as possible. An important thing about it is that it has a tostring function that gets called and since tostring is defined inside function `sum()` it has access to the variable `sum` and its value current value (that is changed by `f()` )

Answer (score 2):

`alert` expects a string. If it doesn't get a string, it will attempt to convert whatever object it receives (and a function is a type of object) into one. If the object has a `toString` method, then that will be called to perform said conversion.

Comment: All objects have a `toString` function, it's just that in most cases it's the default "[object Constructorname]" format. In this case, that method is overridden to produce the result.

Answer (score 1):

The `sum` and `f` functions always return the `f` function, you can invoke it infinite times without getting a result other than the function.

The value is only returned by the overwritten `toString` method of `f` (which actually returns a number):

```
console.log( sum(1)(2) ) // Function(){}
console.log( sum(1)(2).toString() ) // 3
```

The `alert` function implicitly invokes the `toString` method when it casts its arguments to strings.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work as intended in all of the cases... The problem is that `.toString` is expected to return a string, so string methods in provided implementation, would not work, e. g. `sum(2)(3).split()` will cause an error.

Although we might assume `sum()` result will always be expected to be a number, it might not be true in some cases and might be hard to debug, e. g. I noticed the issue when I was testing code initially written with `.toString` only on jsbin.com (it does `split` on console.log argument internally, overriding it).

Instead, `.toString` should look like `return String(result);`. Good thing that `.toString` (when there's no `.valueOf` or modern `Symbol.toPrimitive`) will handle primitives conversion, so code expecting a Number will work as well. The possible issue here might be "double" conversion caused by this.

Better solution might be to use either pair of `.toString` and `.valueOf` or just a single `Symbol.toPrimitive` if you're only targeting modern browsers.

Example using `Symbol.toPrimitive`:

```
function sum(a) {
  let result = a;

  function f(b) {
    result += b;

    return f;
  }

  f[Symbol.toPrimitive] = hint => hint === 'string' ? String(result) : result;

  return f;
}
```

Example using `.toString` and `.valueOf` pair.

```
function sum(a) {
  var result = a;

  function f(b) {
    result += b;

    return f;
  }

  // avoiding double conversion which will happen in case of .toString
  f.valueOf = function() { return result; };
  f.toString = function() { return String(result); };

  return f;
}
```