# How to write a function that can be called with two pairs of parenthesis?

Tags: javascript

Recently, I was asked to write `add(a)(b)` function and this will return `a+b`. I had no clue how to write this sort function in javascript. **How to write this function so that it returns a + b ?**

Comment: Is it **just** `a` and `b`? Or is it possible to have `add(a)(b)(c)(d)`?

Comment: This is called Currying.

Comment: This will surely help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18252084/closure-in-javascript-with-multiple-brackets#18252118

Comment: @Ian - Unless I'm very much mistaken, it would be impossible to do that and still return a scalar. Not unless you know in advance how many arguments there will be.

Comment: @JustinMorgan - See the link i posted. The trick is in providing a `.toString()` to what you return.

Comment: @JustinMorgan The OP seems to be asking about a concept, and the OP just gave an example. They can *want* whatever they want, so I wanted to make sure this wasn't just a simple example. There **are** ways to do what I'm suggesting, but it's annoying. Such as invoking the function one last time without passing any arguments (to signify it's the end of the chain). And **impossible** is quite a strong word

Comment: @Ian - I was going to suggest the `add(a)(b)(c)(d)()` syntax, yes. That should work fine.

Comment: @JustinMorgan Of course, the OP wouldn't have thought of that; usually questions are in the format "I want something that lets me do this: ______". In this case, a variable number of function invocations requires some kind of terminater, or other alternatives

Comment: @techfoobar - Sure, but it's still not technically the same as returning the sum. It would depend on how the requirements were worded.

Comment: @JustinMorgan - Yes. Plus it makes for terrible-to-read code. Just pointed out a possibility.

Comment: @2619: I'm curious to know who asked you to write this function? Was it a job interview, or a homework assignment?

Comment: @CrazyTrain It was assignment.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Write a function that returns a function:

```
function add(a) {
    return function(b) {
        return a + b
    }
}
```

In JavaScript, functions can be used just like normal objects. In fact, [they **are** objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)!

Comment: Wow this got 9 votes that quick! some of my best answers only have 9 votes :(

Comment: @Evan Heh, I'm quite surprised about that too :P this might become my first Reversal badge, actually :P

Comment: *"...can be used just like normal variables"* Did you mean "just like normal *objects*"?

Comment: functions ARE normal objects. you can use them *like* variables.

Comment: @sgroves: That doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

`add` would need to return a function:

```
function add( a ) {
    return function( b ) {
        return a + b;
    }
}

add(1)(2) --> 3
```